# Grouping rows into fixed size arrays in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to aggregate my data in BigQuery into fixed size arrays, for pagination somewhere else. So, starting with something like this:

```
+-------+
|  num  |
+-------+
| one   |
| two   |
| three |
| four  |
| five  |
| six   |
| seven |
| eight |
| nine  |
| ten   |
+-------+
```

I'd like to end up with something like this, given a page size of 5:

```
+------+--------------------------------------+
| page |                 nums                 |
+------+--------------------------------------+
|    0 | ["one","two","three","four","five"]  |
|    1 | ["six","seven","eight","nine","ten"] |
+------+--------------------------------------+
```

I'm currently doing this using `ROW_NUMBER()`. Here's a full code sample that starts with the 10 string rows above, and creates the desired output:

```
bq query "#StandardSQL
-- Create dummy input
WITH input AS (
      SELECT * FROM UNNEST((
         SELECT SPLIT('one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten', ',')
      )) as num
)
-- Paginate it
SELECT page, ARRAY_AGG(num) as nums FROM (
  SELECT *, CAST(FLOOR(row / 5) AS INT64) as page FROM (
    SELECT *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1) - 1) as row FROM input
  )
) GROUP BY page"

+------+--------------------------------------+
| page |                 nums                 |
+------+--------------------------------------+
|    0 | ["one","two","three","four","five"]  |
|    1 | ["six","seven","eight","nine","ten"] |
+------+--------------------------------------+
```

This works well up until there are around 30 million rows or so in the input data, and then I hit the dreaded `Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory.` error, because BQ is trying to calculate the row number for all 30 million+ rows in memory.

What's an alternative way to produce the same output as my example, but that scales to over 100 million rows without breaking?

Comment: when you say `30 million entries` - do you mean `30 million rows` with each having values like `one`, `two`, and so on?

Comment: Yes, over 30 million rows per `PARTITION BY`

Comment: what partition? I see no mentioning of partitions in question. I think i understood what output you expect  - but I still don't understand what is input data and how it is structured

Comment: You see `PARTITION BY` in the query? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts

Comment: That's the part that's causing the OOM though, because BQ does the analytic functions in memory on a single node AFAICT. The goal is to replace the `OVER ... PARTITION BY` section with something else :)

Comment: The input data doesn't matter - assume it's 30 million rows, a single column.

Comment: Updated the question to hopefully make it clearer!

Comment: have you considered using [tabledata.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list) api instead? it has all paging functionality that you probably need

Comment: I don't need to page through the data, I want to export the data pre-grouped per page for another system that wants the data in that format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201165/discussion-between-ben-dowling-and-mikhail-berlyant).

Comment: Windowing and ordering are not good parallelizable ... the task is to get rid of them. You'd need to add some logic to your data that allows that - like dates (grouped to weeks or months) or something

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
#StandardSQL
WITH input AS (
  SELECT x, CONCAT('item_',CAST(y AS STRING), '_', CAST(x AS STRING)) item
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 1000000)) x,
    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100)) y
), temp AS (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(item) line, CAST(100 * RAND() - 0.5 AS INT64) grp
  FROM input
  GROUP BY grp
)
SELECT grp, page, items FROM temp, 
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(line, r'(?:[^,]+,){4}[^,]+|(?:[^,]+,)*[^,]+')) items WITH OFFSET page;
```

it produces pages with below page-size distribution (obviously this can slightly vary because of use of `RAND()` ):

```
Row page-size   pages    
1   5           19999958     
2   3           29   
3   2           21   
4   4           18   
5   1           5
```

As you can see in above - `input` just mimics table with 100M rows and the rest of code produces something like below

[image]

Option 2: To address those not full pages

```
Row page-size   pages    
2   3           29   
3   2           21   
4   4           18   
5   1           5
```

Below script can be used

```
#StandardSQL
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_result AS 
WITH input AS (
  SELECT x, CONCAT('item_',CAST(y AS STRING), '_', CAST(x AS STRING)) item
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 1000000)) x,
    UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100)) y
), temp AS (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(item) line, CAST(100 * RAND() - 0.5 AS INT64) grp
  FROM input
  GROUP BY grp
)
SELECT grp, page, x FROM temp, 
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(line, r'(?:[^,]+,){4}[^,]+|(?:[^,]+,)*[^,]+')) x WITH OFFSET page;

SELECT * FROM temp_result WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(x)) = 5 UNION ALL
SELECT -1, page, x FROM (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(x) line FROM temp_result WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(x)) < 5
), UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(line, r'(?:[^,]+,){4}[^,]+|(?:[^,]+,)*[^,]+')) x WITH OFFSET page
```

Which produces below (with minimum to none - non-full pages) - 20M pages each with 5 items

[image]

Note: I do understand it is most likely not exactly what OP expected, but this is the best i was able to get into that actually works without erroring on 100M rows

Comment: I need to preserve order too (or can ORDER BY a field). Can his approach be updated to handle that?

Comment: o( there was no any mentioning of ORDER BY in your question - neither in text nor in query!  anyway - most likely yes - for option 1, but for option 2 there will be a problem as it mixes all those leftovers together to do final split (marked as group=-1)

Comment: There wasn't, but the order was implicitly preserved, rather than the results being randomized.

Comment: It I didn't care about order than I could just replace `ROW_NUMEBR()` with `RAND()` in my original query, to give something like this: 

```SELECT page, ARRAY_AGG(num) as nums FROM (
    SELECT *, CAST(RAND() * $NUM_PAGES AS INT64) as page FROM input
) GROUP BY page
```

Comment: I repeat my point - there is/was nothing in your question (including code) that imply order explicitly or implicitly. And, BTW - ROW_NUMBER BY ITSELF DOES NOT GUARANTEE ANY ORDER so don't be fooled if you think it does! Meantime, my answer clearly does not take any order into account . So, just ignore it then and hopefully someone will give you better answer :o)

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous discussion, source table also needs to be sorted to preserve order. The question becomes, how can you do a global sorting of a table which is too big. Here is my thinking:

1. Since whole table cannot be sorted, if cost if not a problem, the big table can be segmented and sorted per segment.
2. In order to create segments evenly, we can create a sample table. Below query samples 1/1000 of data from "large_table".

```sql
create or replace table sample_table as
select * from large_table where rand() < 0.001;
```

3. With sampled table, generate an array of segment boundary points, say we want to segment the large table in 3 parts, the query will be like

```sql
SELECT array_agg(struct(value, sample_point)) from 
(SELECT *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY value) - 1) as row_number FROM `sample_table` )
JOIN UNNEST([1/3, 2/3]) sample_point
ON row_number = CAST(sample_point * (select count(1) from `sample_table` ) AS INT64)
```

4. Use [BigQuery Scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) to iterate over the array of segment boundaries, run original pagination query but with clause `WHERE value > lower_bound and value <= upper_bound`, and insert the pagination result into an intermediate table. If it is acceptable that there are a couple of pages with less than 5 elements, this works.
5. If it is hard requirement that all page but last one must have 5 elements. It can still be done by after each iteration, fetch last page from intermediate table, and make lower bound of next iteration the first element and delete last page. (Note that there is a corner case to deal with if value is not unique and the first element may be a duplicate).

**Cost**

Sampling: 1 scan

Segmented sorting: Ceiling(count_of_table / 30 million) of scans.